# Awaiting to a normal function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Is it possible await to a function that is not a promise?
Maybe a function that cannot fail.

for example:

```
async function doWork() {
    const newData = await cannotFail();
    console.log("done: "+ newData);
}

function cannotFail() {
  var data = //cannot fail code . . .
    return data;
}

doWork();
```

I was thinking maybe with another syntax this option makes sense.

Comment: what's the point of awaiting a non-async function? If `cannotFail` function contains an async code that is callback-based, you can wrap a promise around it and return that promise from the `cannotFail` function.

Comment: you can actually await a non-promise, the await just does nothing. May be useful if something may or may not return a Promise dependant on some condition.

Comment: Async is not the same as try catch and has less to do with failing/non failing functions. It is for asynchronous code. Your function will run very well, but you do not need an await. Remove that and it is still the same. Maybe you want to ask something else?

Answer (score 5):

Consider these two examples

```js
async function getData(){
  return "some data";
}

async function doSomething() {
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
}

doSomething()
```

```js
function getData(){
  return "some data";
}

async function doSomething(){
  const data = getData();
  console.log(data);
}

doSomething();
```

The result is exactly the same. You only use `await` when you want to wait for an `asnyc` function like it is synchronous. Normal functions already are synchronous.

And yes it is possible to use await on a normal function

```js
function getData(){
  return 'some data';
}

async function doSomething(){
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
 }
 
 doSomething();
```

There is just no reason to.

Comment: I found an example where this is useful: I wrote a ModalProvider in React, and it receives an "onConfirm" callback. We want to close the modal after the call to onConfirm(), but we do not know if onConfirm is async => 
`await onConfirm();closeModal()`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `await` with an expression that does not evaluate to a promise. Whether that is useful, is questionable.

First of all, when `await` is followed by an expression that does not evaluate to a promise object, it is turned into one -- a resolved promise.

The main difference you get by using `await` with a non-promise or a resolved promise, is that `await` will make the `async` function return. This behaviour is not dependent on whether the promise is already resolved or not. `await` always postpones the further execution of the function by placing that resuming-job on the promise job queue.

See the difference here:

```js
async function test() {
    let a = 1; // Without await
    console.log(a);
    return 2;
}

test().then(console.log);
console.log("end of main, synchronous code");
```

And with `await`

```js
async function test() {
    let a = await 1; // With await
    console.log(a);
    return 2;
}

test().then(console.log);
console.log("end of main, synchronous code");
```

Note the different order of execution.

Comment: Ok, its probably what I meant, so if I dont specify that a function is async it will wait for it anyway?
and why the second code is different? the `console.log` need to wait to the `a` variable in order to log it even if you dont add the `await`.

Comment: That are several questions. *"If I don't specify that a function is `async`, it will wait for it either way?"*. If you refer to the *expression* that follows  `await`, the rule is: if that expression is a promise (which is the case when you call an `async` function there), then `await` will await that promise to be resolved. It the *expression* does not evaluate to a promise (which is the case when you call a non-`async` function there), then `await` will treat that expression as a *resolved* promise. It will *still* make the function return first.

Comment: *"why the second code is different?"*: because `await` *always* makes the wrapping `async` function *return*. The remaining code that follows below an `await` is *never* executed immediately. Never. That remaining code is always called from the event queue.

Comment: *"the `console.log` need to wait to the `a` variable"*: that is an odd way to phrase it. The code that follows below an `await` (like that `console.log`) is *never* executed immediately. The function's execution context is saved when an `await` executes. It has nothing to do with the expression that the `await` operates on. It can be anything. It can be `null`, it can be `1`, it can be the evaluation of a function. Whatever it is, `await` will make the wrapping function to *return*. Always.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary, but it is possible:

```
const newData = await Promise.resolve( cannotFail() );
```